# activity or fragment? help me out to choose

Tags: android, android-activity, popup, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

There are 3 similar screens in my app. So doubt is what should I create for these screens Activity or Fragment.[image: Login Screen Popup]
[image: SignUp Screen Popup]
[image: Forgot Password Popup]

Comment: I'd go with Fragments

Comment: Is it possible with in fragment while I'm having different type and number of widgets?

Comment: Use different fragments - replace the fragment as needed

Comment: understand. Thank you. God bless...

Answer (score 0):

As per the given UI, Fragments would be the best option.
I would suggest you, use the Navigation component for the fragment navigation.

You can visit the documentation of Navigation Component by Jetpack:
 [Navigation component Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you for documentation suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use fragments for this scenario, because fragments gives the freedom to reuse the components and also maintains the back navigation in such scenarios.

Also do take a look at the [Android's Navigation Component.](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started), as you can maintain the flow of the navigation of the application properly.

Comment: Thanks you for valuable suggestion